# How can i enable caching for a Sitecore ControllerRendering

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

Is there a way to enable Sitecore caching for a ControllerRendering declared statically in a layout? In Webforms you could declare a rendering's caching settings like this:

`<sc:Sublayout ID="slMyControl" path="~/path/to/my/control.ascx" VaryByParm="true" Cachable="true" runat="server" />`

However, when I use the Html helper there is no overload on the Controller method to accept caching parameters?

`@Html.Sitecore().Controller("NAMESPACE", "ACTION")`

I'm running Sitecore 7.2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want statically bind a controller rendering, you should use the `Rendering()` method on the html helper. There you can define the caching with parameters:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("<your rendering definition item id>", new { Cacheable = true, CacheKey = "my_rendering", Cache_VaryByData = true })
```

The parameters should have the same name as used in the sublayout, with a `Cache_` prefix.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to do the job nicely! Do you have to declare the cache settings inline though, as it doesn't seem to pickup any cache settings declared on the rendering item?

Comment: @RobEarlam as far as I know, the cache settings on the rendering item are only taken for dynamic binding.

Answer (score 0):

This works and I tried it with Controller rendering. You can verify it by attaching it to the worker process and it should not hit the break point when refresh the same page. It will also depend on what parameters have been used for caching.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is a professional Q & A site. Please visit [answer]